# Custom Error Handler for Http Error 405 in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis-7, error-handling

I can't seem to figure out how to custom handle this error. I have a endpoint defined like this:

[HttpGet]
   public ActionResult Test() { ... }

If I try to POST to this endpoint it throws the http 405 error which is correct. The problem is I want to provide a custom error page and not the IIS default one. I've tried breaking in the application_error method in global.asax but it never get's called, and I've tried adding the `<customErrors />` section in web.config but to no avail.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Using firebug or the equivalent, do you see a 405 or a 500 status code in the browser?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using MVC3?  If so, watch out for

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
  filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
}
```

in your global.asax.

This filter will catch any exception thrown in a controller and make it a 500 response code.  It will then try and find a View called "Error".  Comment this out and customErrors will work as you expect.

Also, double check for [HandleError] attributes on the action method or controller you are using.

Comment: I commented out the global filter and neither my action or controller have the attribute on it. Any other ideas?