# ASP.NET Override all standard http error responses

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have created a custom object that i use to generate a json error response for all error. The issue i am having is there are some errors that i cant catch. For example, if i try to call an action that does not support GET the default response is

> {"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method
>   'GET'."}

This is fine, but i want to control the format. I want to control every single automated error like this so i can make sure that nothing gets output that i dont want to be output. I need to be able to gracefully let the client know if a code exception occurs.

I found this and this seems to be what i am looking for, but it doesnt seem to be catching the errors as there are no matching actions for these . [How to override all standard error pages in WebAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14530387/how-to-override-all-standard-error-pages-in-webapi)

I tried to implement this, but i still get the same error message from above even when i have this in the main controller.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[ActionName("405")]
[HttpGet]
public string Status405()
{
    return "error";
}
```

I was hoping there would be an onerror event or something that would act as a catch all so i could override everything. I tried to work based off the HttpResponseEx

```
public class ErrorFilter : System.Web.Http.HttpResponseException
{
    public override string Message
    {
        get
        {
            return "My custom response based on whatever params are in this error";
        }
    }
}
```

This doesnt work either and i can see why as it doesnt tap into any events that get triggered.

Surely there is a way to do this. How is it normally done?

Answer (score 0):

In the web.config, you need to turn on custom errors. By default it's set to remote, which allows the developer to see the stack trace and the end user to see a nice error page. You want to set this to on. See here for more details https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Wouldnt this only apply to messages that IIS handles? For example if someone tries to access a directory iis will display a 403. In this scenario the actual controller appears to be generating this response not IIS.

Comment: Valid point. Check your global.asax file for something like

public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
  filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
}

based on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8128302/custom-error-handler-for-http-error-405-in-mvc